# how to extract month from date in hive and group it by month

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have hive table as below and now I need to  group data by avg of each month

sample hive table:

```
 dat        amazon  tesla  infosys  facebook  apple 
 03/01/17  753.67   808.01 216.99   14.74     116.86
 04/01/17  757.18   807.77 226.99   15.13     118.69
 05/02/17  780.45   813.02 226.75   15.02     120.67
 06/05/17  795.99   825.21 229.01   14.82     123.41
```

sample output:

```
month  amazon  tesla  infosys  facebook  apple 
 1     782.2   843.23 548.87    24.42    143.35
 2     743.2   896.12 453.34    44.34    143.55
```

I need avg value of every month please help me

Comment: Few questions: What the use to have month without year? Is it only one year in the table? And the date is in dd/MM/yy format, right?

Comment: Also how it happened that tesla average is 843.23 for month 1 if the biggest value in the initial table is 808.01 ? The same for other figures. And why month 5 is absent in the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select cast(substr(dat, 4, 2) as int) as month,
       avg(amazon)                    as amazon,
       avg(tesla)                     as tesla,
       avg(infosys)                   as infosys,
       avg(facebook)                  as facebook,
       avg(apple)                     as apple
  from tablename
 group by cast(substr(dat, 4, 2) as int);
```